# I need help using the merge function with oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have three tables (partial_subs_2015,partial_subs_new and full_subscribers) which contain customer phone numbers and customer names).
Basically what i want to do is load phone numbers numbers and customer names from partial_subs_new to partial_subs_2015, in a way that if those numbers already exist in the using partial_subs_2015 nothing happens (update clause) and when those numbers exist in full_subscribers then they are deleted from partial_subs_2015 (delete clause). And lastly if numbers in partial_subs_new are not found in  partial_subs_2015 (no match) then they are inserted into that table (partial_subs_2015)  (insert clause).

My query runs indefinitely without and i dnt know why.
Any help will be appreciated. Basically this will give me a dynamic table whereby if customers convert to full, they are deleted from the partial_subs_2015 table. I have this query:

```
merge into partial_subs_2015 p using partial_subs_new e
on ( e.customer_name =  p.customer_name)
when matched then update set p.msisdn = p.msisdn
delete where p.msisdn  in (select msisdn from full_subscribers)
when not matched then insert (msisdn,customer_name)
values (e.msisdn,e.customer_name)
```

Comment: shouldn't you be matching on a primary key like msisdn not the customer name?

Comment: Please show the table layouts, sample data, and expected output.

Comment: partial_subs_2015  Customer Number Customer Name
079-012-345 name 1 
079-012-346 name 2
079-012-347 name 3
079-012-348 name 4
079-012-349 name 5
079-012-350 name 6
079-012-351 name 7
.. ..

Comment: Partial_subs_new Column1
Customer Number Customer Name
079-012-345 name 1 
079-012-346 name 2
079-012-347 name 3
079-012-348 name 4
079-012-349 name 5
079-012-350 name 6
079-012-351 name 7
079-012-352 name 8
079-012-353 name 9
079-012-354 name 10
079-012-355 name 11
079-012-356 name 12
079-012-357 name 13

Comment: full_subscribers Column1
Customer Number Customer Name
079-012-345 name 1 
079-012-346 name 2
079-012-347 name 3
079-012-348 name 4
079-012-349 name 5
079-012-350 name 6
079-012-351 name 7
079-012-352 name 8
079-012-353 name 9
079-012-354 name 10
079-012-355 name 11
079-012-356 name 12
079-012-357 name 13
079-012-358 name 14
079-012-359 name 15
079-012-360 name 16
079-012-361 name 17
079-012-362 name 18

Comment: those are the table structures. I just want to load numbers and customer names from partial_subs_new to partial subs_2015 which do not already exist there. And again which do not exist in full subscribers